# Dynamic Chart Depiction On Excel

Tags: excel, ms-office

I've a chart in excel that shows a person's start and end date. Depending upon day difference, it displays the data as follows:

[image: Current Image]

It shows person id in the left and the bar depicts the total days. For the day difference, I used this formula:

```
=(C2 - B2) + 1
```

Simple enough! But now I've a requirement where I've to show fixed days in the horizontal line, say days up to 60 and if a person has total days of 10 calculating its start and end dates, the chart should depict accordingly. As an example, a person has total 10 days from 07/01/2021 to 07/10/2021, then the chart should increment the bar chart one by one. Say 07/01/2021 is day 1, 07/02/2021 day 2 and so on. The bar chart will raise based on the days counted. I am not sure if this can be done using chart or any other tool in excel? Would expect your valuable suggestion in this regard - Thanks.

Comment: You can use a third helper column with two dates where the first one is your starting date and the second one is the date of today or the end date.
By defining name tagged values via >Formulas>Defined Names>Name Manager you can  `OFFSET` the third column and add its values in the combined chart as a line and chart maximum.

Comment: Can you look into this @Алексей Р? Though got a solution but somehow unable to resolve it.

Answer (score 1):

The first cell per column is given a name for example `B2` shall be named `"Start"`.
After defining this variable, make new one and insert this formula:
`=OFFSET(*your_sheetname*!*your_variable*;0;0;COUNTA(*your_sheetname*!$B:$B)-1;1)`

This will be done two times (Start, End) and then make a chart an insert a new dataseries.
In the "Select Data values" window edit your series. For "Series Values" enter the "Start" variable. For the "Axis Values" enter your date as variables.
Always enter:

`=*your_sheetname*!*your_variable*`

If you add data to your columns the charts axis will grow or shrink.

I added some example code I used for making a line chart with labelled dataseries and date as axis. Note how also the maximum range of axis can be set via `VBA`:

```vb
Sub CustomChart()

    Dim j, i, cols, chartname, sheetname, pos_x, pos_y
    Dim my_chart As Chart, sc As Series
    
    'sheetname = "whatever you feel like" 'change as you wish
    sheetname = ActiveSheet.Name
    chartname = "myChart2"
    
    pos_x = 300  'x position where the chart will occur (counting from "A1")
    pos_y = 300  'y position where the chart will occur
    
'#############################################################################
ActiveSheet.Shapes.AddChart2(227, xlLine, pos_x, pos_y).Name = chartname
    With ActiveSheet.Shapes(chartname).Line
        .Visible = msoTrue
        .ForeColor.RGB = RGB(0, 0, 0)
        .Transparency = 0
        .Weight = 1.5
    End With
        
'#############################################################################
'Make new dataseries
        'delete old datasets
        ActiveSheet.ChartObjects(chartname).Activate
        j = ActiveChart.FullSeriesCollection.Count
        If j = 0 Then GoTo LineB
        For i = 1 To j
            ActiveChart.FullSeriesCollection(i).Delete
        Next i
LineB:
    'Insert new one(s)
    ' #1
    ActiveSheet.ChartObjects(chartname).Activate
    ActiveChart.SeriesCollection.NewSeries
    ActiveChart.FullSeriesCollection(1).Name = "=""Title1"""
    ActiveChart.FullSeriesCollection(1).Values = "=" & sheetname & "!*your_variable*"
    ActiveChart.FullSeriesCollection(1).XValues = "=" & sheetname & "!*your_label_variable*"

    ' #2
    ActiveChart.SeriesCollection.NewSeries
    ActiveChart.FullSeriesCollection(2).Name = "=""Title2"""
    ActiveChart.FullSeriesCollection(2).Values = "=" & sheetname & "!*your_variable_2*"
    ActiveChart.FullSeriesCollection(2).XValues = "=" & sheetname & "!*your_label_variable*"
    
'##################################################################################################
    ' Set labels
    Set my_chart = ActiveSheet.ChartObjects(chartname).Chart
    
        'delete old one(s)
        my_chart.SetElement (msoElementDataLabelNone)
    
    With my_chart.Axes(xlCategory)      ' axis adjustment
        .CategoryType = xlCategoryScale ' not XlCategoryType.xlAutomaticScale | XlCategoryType.xlTimeScale
        .TickLabels.NumberFormat = "DD.MM.YYYY hh:mm" 'change to your format
        .TickLabels.Orientation = xlUpward
    End With
    
'    cols = Array("F", "L")  'column(s) containing labels
     cols = Array("A")       'in your example you have just one label column
     For j = 1 To my_chart.SeriesCollection.Count
        Set sc = my_chart.SeriesCollection(j)
        For i = 2 To sc.Points.Count                 '2 if you have headers, 1 if you have not
             sc.Points(i).ApplyDataLabels
             sc.Points(i).DataLabel.Text = Range(cols(j - 1) & i + 6).Value 'if you have text in the frist 5 rows you must add 6, if not add zero
        Next i

          'set datalabels above series
           my_chart.SetElement (msoElementDataLabelTop)

Next j
    
End Sub
```

Hope this gives you an impression of what I meant.

Comment: I am bit lost with the above. Can you share the same thing with a sample excel file? So I can download and do some R&D on it. Never mind @Capt.Krusty. I am novice to this `VBA` programming.

Comment: In Excel, go to Developer>Visual Basic
In VBA go to View and open the "Code", "Immediate" and "Locals" window.
Then copy+paste my code into the code window and set your cursor into the code.
Press "F8" on your keyboard and go through the code step by step (line by line).
Make the VBA window smaller or put it onto a second monitor to see what each step does in your excel sheet. I am sure you will R&D the code by clicking through and "debugging" if something is missing.